# Always show number to nearest hundreth

Tags: php, rounding

I'm using the `round($number,2)` function in php to round a `$number` to the nearest hundredth. It works great, but if the hundredth decimal is equal to `0`, it wont display the `0`. I need the number to read:

```
1.70
```

not

```
1.7
```

Does anyone know a good method to achieve this? I'm doing it with about 20 numbers on a page. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pad your numbers, something like this will work:

`number_format((float)$number, 2, '.', '');`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
echo sprintf('%.2f', 1.7);
```

Shows:

```
1.70
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$number = 1.7;

$number = sprintf("%0.2f",$number);

echo $number;

?>
```

Output

```
1.70
```